# Form Themes. What differ functions: {{ form_label(foo) }} vs {{ block('form_label') }}?

Tags: symfony, twig

In form themes once there is such notation:

```
{%- block form_row -%}
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

and once such:

```
{%- block number_widget -%}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{%- endblock number_widget -%}
```

The `block()` function evokes a block, so what `form_widget(form)` function does?

Answer (score 0):

The function is using a parameter (that is `form`), while the block is not. So, you can't use `{{ block('form_label') }}` to render a specific label for a form, but you can use it in another block (where likely you want to customize somehow all your labels)